# How can I get the Flagged mail Exchange

Tags: mailkit

[When I mark the message in this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7qIi.jpg)

I use the method

```
var  uids= folder.Search(SearchQuery.DeliveredAfter(DateTime.Parse("2016-9-29")).And(SearchQuery.Flagged));
```

cannot get the flagged mail,
but when I use method

```
folder.AddFlags(new UniqueId(1693), MessageFlags.Flagged, false);
folder.Expunge();
```

the mail will be flagged  and When I use the method

```
var  uids= folder.Search(SearchQuery.DeliveredAfter(DateTime.Parse("2016-9-29")).And(SearchQuery.Flagged));
```

I can get the flagged mail,I don't know why, and how can I get the flagged mail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are conflating 2 different ways of "flagging" a message. Outlook does not set the `MessageFlags.Flagged` flag, that's why `Search()` does not find it.

Most likely Outlook either does not store anything on the IMAP server at all (and that state is stored locally in the .pst file) -or- it stores a custom `UserFlags` string on the IMAP server that you will need to figure out.

If you know of a particular message on your IMAP server that has this custom flag, you can use the `Fetch()` method with `MessageSummaryItems.Flags` to request what flags are set. Then, you can examine the `item.UserFlags` and hope that you find what you are looking for.

Comment: thank you for your help！I'm very sorry for the late reply, I found the Flaged Message  in the MessageHeader["X-Message-Flag"]